# R- list of combination of 3 item sets from n items

Tags: r

I am getting a tough time in selecting the combinations of factors.

I have a vector as `("Ryan", "Leo", "Jack","Harry","Edd")`.

I want to get the list of of all combinations taken  3 of the names once.

I want to do it in R. Probably a resultant matrix will help me.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `combn`

```
t(combn(vec1, 3))
```